# How can I disable the core migrations?

Tags: migrations, 10

After I enabled the Drupal Migrate module in Drupal 10, every time I do a `drush ms` I get a page of errors about Drupal 7 migrations like the following one.

> [error]  Could not retrieve source count from d6_filter_format: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'PRODUCTION_content_shared.filter_formats' doesn't exist: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "expression"

Is there a way to disable migrations by migration_tags (all the Drupal 6 migrations are tagged "Drupal 6") or if necessary by ID?

Comment: I know I can do `drush ms --tag my_tag` or `drush ms --group my_group` which will avoid the Drupal 6 and Drupal 7 migrations and errors. Still would be nice to disable the D6 migrations however so I can just `drush ms`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`hook_migrations_plugins_alter`](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/drupal/-/blob/10.2.x/core/modules/migrate/migrate.api.php?ref_type=heads#L203).

For example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_migration_plugins_alter().
 */
function my_module_migration_plugins_alter(array &$migrations) {
  $migrations = array_filter($migrations, fn(array $m) => $m['provider'] == 'my_module');
}
```